# Cypress cancelling the XHR calls while executing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, automated-tests, cypress

We are automating the UI Application using Cypress. When we are executing the scripts from the Cypress desktop application,  the xhr (API) calls are getting canceled automatically and the execution is getting failed.
We have tried cy.wait() with maximum time in spec file and we have tried the  "responseTimeout",  "taskTimeout",  "execTimeout"  in cypress.json file. but still, the execution is failing in the first test case itself

Below is the sample code.

```
it('scenario1',()=>{
    cy.get('').click();
    cy.get('').click()
    cy.get('').click();
    cy.get('').type('');
    cy.get('.btnsearch.ng-star-inserted > .btnsearch').click();
    cy.wait(20000);
    cy.get(':nth-child(2) > .cdk-column-clientName').then((ele) => {
      expect(ele.text().trim()).to.contain('somevalue');
    });
    cy.screenshot();
  });

it('Scenario2',()=>{
  cy.get('').click();
  cy.get('').click();
  cy.get('').click();
  cy.get('').type('');
  cy.get('').click();
  cy.wait(10000);
  cy.get(':nth-child(2) > .cdk-column-policyNumber').then((ele) => {
    expect(ele.text().trim()).equal('somevlue');
  });
  cy.screenshot();
});
```

In the above script, it's failing in the first test case itself.

Comment: Could you provide an example of such error?

Comment: @Jonah Can you please check now

Comment: Could you post the error message or it is just an message that the request was cancelled? No additional information?

Comment: Hi @Jonah, there is no error message from cypress, it's cancelling the XHR calls and the execution window is closed automatically.